# How to expose C# .net core Web Api endpoint to be callable by other applications?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

My angular SPA application has controller api GET endpoint which return some data in string format.
I want that endpoint to be exposed and make it available for other applications to give a call.

I am using Oauth2.0 token based authentication and Azure active directory application is also setup which has redirect Uris.

> I have tried to call endpoint using postman using Client Credentials
> as grant type but i endup getting response in HTML format.
>
> [image]

Comment: What if you generate the token and invoke the API using Authorization Bearer token?

Comment: @user1672994 still i am getting same HTML response. Do i need do some settings in AAD?

Comment: Your API should be returning 401 in case of unauthorized request instead of 302. Have you setup the routing correctly?

Comment: why don't you simply remove the endpoint from your web app, create a separate API and then call it from all applications that need it? No need to complicate things

Comment: @user1672994 The endpoint does return result if you add url in browser

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Right but still i have to enable oauth2.0 authentication and i am not sure what settings are required in AAD in order endpoint to work.

Comment: that's neither here nor there. the API can be protected with oauth2 at which point you just to learn how to access it properly. do a bit of research on API Oauth2

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Thanks !